# Dot product with arrays

Tags: java, for-loop, dot-product

In class we had to write a small code using Dot Product to find the sum of two arrays(array a and array b).  I have written my code however when I run it it does not give me the answer. My professor said my loop was wrong however I do not think it is. Is the part that says `i<a.length` not allowed in a for loop parameter? Because even if I set it to n it still does not give me the sum.

Here is my code:

```
public class arrayExample {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        int[] a = {1,2,2,1};
        int[] b = {1,2,2,1};
        int n = a.length;

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += a[n] * b[n];    
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i < a.length` is indeed valid in the loop parameter. Not sure what your instructor is talking about there.

Comment: What does it output?  How does it differ from your expected output?

Comment: What's `n`? Does this even compile?

Comment: @JustinL. it was not showing me anything, however I realized from the answer below I was supposed to multiple a[i]*b[i] (not a[n]*b[n]) Thank you :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider The program did compile, n was supposed to represent the length of array a, however I took it out.

Comment: @hexafraction Thank you for the assistance, I realized the sum= line was incorrect

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`n` isn't the loop control variable, it's `a.length` which is an out of bounds index. You probably meant

```
sum += a[i] * b[i];
```

And, although it does not matter directly, you *probably* meant your `for`-loop to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

(I would assume that's the reason you have `n` in the first place.)

Comment: @arshajii Thank you for the assistance.  I changed the line to sum += a[i]*b[i] and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class arrayExample 
{
  public static void main (String [] args) 
   {

     int[] a = {1,2,2,1};
     int[] b = {1,2,2,1};
     int n = a.length;

     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     {
        sum += a[i] * b[i];    
     }

     System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```